# USB, HID. Correct "Usage Page (Button)" declaration

Tags: usb, stm32, hid

**Why do I need 5 commands to declare a Usage Page (Button)?**

If these commands are not for the button, then what are they for?

```
  0x05, 0x01,        /* Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)     */
  0x09, 0x02,        /* Usage (Mouse)                          */
  0xA1, 0x01,        /* Collection (Application)               */
  0x09, 0x01,        /*   Usage (Pointer)                      */
  0xA1, 0x00,        /*   Collection (Physical)                */
  0x05, 0x09,        /*     Usage Page (Button)                */
```

For coordinates this code is used

```
  0x05, 0x01,        /*     Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls) */
  0x09, 0x30,        /*     Usage (X)                          */
  0x09, 0x31,        /*     Usage (Y)                          */
```

This is the standard USB report descriptor for the mouse. I copied it from auto-generated code.

```
__ALIGN_BEGIN static uint8_t HID_MOUSE_ReportDesc[HID_MOUSE_REPORT_DESC_SIZE] __ALIGN_END =
{
  0x05, 0x01,        /* Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)     */
  0x09, 0x02,        /* Usage (Mouse)                          */
  0xA1, 0x01,        /* Collection (Application)               */
  0x09, 0x01,        /*   Usage (Pointer)                      */
  0xA1, 0x00,        /*   Collection (Physical)                */
  0x05, 0x09,        /*     Usage Page (Button)                */
  0x19, 0x01,        /*     Usage Minimum (0x01)               */
  0x29, 0x03,        /*     Usage Maximum (0x03)               */
  0x15, 0x00,        /*     Logical Minimum (0)                */
  0x25, 0x01,        /*     Logical Maximum (1)                */
  0x95, 0x03,        /*     Report Count (3)                   */
  0x75, 0x01,        /*     Report Size (1)                    */
  0x81, 0x02,        /*     Input (Data,Var,Abs)               */
  0x95, 0x01,        /*     Report Count (1)                   */
  0x75, 0x05,        /*     Report Size (5)                    */
  0x81, 0x01,        /*     Input (Const,Array,Abs)            */
  0x05, 0x01,        /*     Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls) */
  0x09, 0x30,        /*     Usage (X)                          */
  0x09, 0x31,        /*     Usage (Y)                          */
  0x09, 0x38,        /*     Usage (Wheel)                      */
  0x15, 0x81,        /*     Logical Minimum (-127)             */
  0x25, 0x7F,        /*     Logical Maximum (127)              */
  0x75, 0x08,        /*     Report Size (8)                    */
  0x95, 0x03,        /*     Report Count (3)                   */
  0x81, 0x06,        /*   Input (Data,Var,Rel)                 */
  0xC0,              /*   End Collection                       */
  0x09, 0x3C,        /*   Usage (Motion Wakeup)                */
  0x05, 0xFF,        /*   Usage Page (Reserved 0xFF)           */
  0x09, 0x01,        /*   Usage (0x01)                         */
  0x15, 0x00,        /*   Logical Minimum (0)                  */
  0x25, 0x01,        /*   Logical Maximum (1)                  */
  0x75, 0x01,        /*   Report Size (1)                      */
  0x95, 0x02,        /*   Report Count (2)                     */
  0xB1, 0x22,        /*   Feature (Data,Var,Abs,NoWrp)         */
  0x75, 0x06,        /*   Report Size (6)                      */
  0x95, 0x01,        /*   Report Count (1)                     */
  0xB1, 0x01,        /*   Feature (Const,Array,Abs,NoWrp)      */
  0xC0               /* End Collection                         */
};
```

In the HID Descriptor Tool, I declared the Usage Page (Button) in one line and did not receive any warnings.

HID Descriptor Tool interface image

[image]

There is also an example of using the button here.
Only one command is used:  Usage Page (Button)
https://eleccelerator.com/tutorial-about-usb-hid-report-descriptors/

The following is written here
https://eleccelerator.com/tutorial-about-usb-hid-report-descriptors/

Ah but we are not done, in order to make the computer know that this is a mouse, we do

```
USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
USAGE (Mouse)
COLLECTION (Application)
    USAGE (Pointer)
    COLLECTION (Physical)
    
    ... What we wrote already goes here
    
    END COLLECTION
END COLLECTION
```

This is done so that the computer understands that this is a mouse button, and not a button, for example, a joystick.
Ok this code can be used for that

```
  0x05, 0x01, /* Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls) */
  0x09, 0x02, /* Usage (Mouse) */
```

What is this code for?

```
USAGE (Pointer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HID mouse will always have an X/Y pointer.

If you want a minimal HID device with only buttons, you can implement it as a HID joystick or gamepad.

Example:

```c
const uint8_t report_descr_hid_joystick_btn3[] =
{
    UsagePage(USB_HID_GENERIC_DESKTOP),
    Usage(USB_HID_JOYSTICK),
    Collection(USB_HID_APPLICATION),

    // 3 buttons
    UsagePage(USB_HID_BUTTONS),
    UsageMinimum(1),
    UsageMaximum(3),
    LogicalMinimum(0),
    LogicalMaximum(1),
    PhysicalMinimum(0),
    PhysicalMaximum(1),
    ReportSize(1),
    ReportCount(3),
    Input(USB_HID_INPUT_DATA | USB_HID_INPUT_VARIABLE | USB_HID_INPUT_ABS),
    // padding
    ReportSize(5),
    ReportCount(1),
    Input(USB_HID_INPUT_CONSTANT | USB_HID_INPUT_VARIABLE | USB_HID_INPUT_ABS),

    EndCollection
};
```

---

**Edit**

> Why does this construction have exactly this sequence?
>
> Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls),
> Usage (Mouse),
> Collection (Application),
> Usage (Pointer),
> Collection (Physical).
>
> If I do this sequence, the code stops working:
>
> Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls),
> Usage (Mouse),
> Usage (Pointer),
> Collection (Application),
> Collection (Physical).
>
> This has something to do with collections, but I don’t understand why this is necessary.

```
Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls) 
Usage (Mouse) 
Usage (Pointer) 
Collection (Application) 
Collection (Physical)
```

Here `Usage (Pointer)` is wrong because it's overriding `Usage (Mouse)`. And HID doesn't support `Usage (Pointer)` within the context of `Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)`.

Comment: Why does this construction have exactly this sequence?
Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls),
Usage (Mouse),
Collection (Application),
Usage (Pointer),
Collection (Physical).
If I do this sequence, the code stops working:
Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls),
Usage (Mouse),
Usage (Pointer),
Collection (Application),
Collection (Physical).
This has something to do with collections, but I don’t understand why this is necessary.